# PHP image resize script rotate image uploaded from iPhone Camera

Tags: php, ios, iphone

The following script rotate portrait images. How can I change it to maintain the orientation (no rotation, just resize)?

**Update**
The script only rotates portrait images when uploaded with iPhone using the Camera. Portrait images uploaded with iPhone from the Library does not get rotated, and portrait images uploaded on desktop does not get rotated.

**Preview before upload**
[image: Preview before upload]

**Image after resize if the previewed image above was uploaded from iPhone camera (see PHP and Class below)**
[image]

**Image after resize if the previewed image above was uploaded from iPhone library (taken by camera the same way as above)**
[image]

**PHP**

```
include("classes/resize.class.php");
// *** 1) Initialise / load image
$resizeObj = new resize($fileLocation);
$resizeObj -> resizeImage(320, 320, 'crop');
$resizeObj -> saveImage($fileLocationSq, 100);
```

**Class**

```
<?php


        class resize
        {
            // *** Class variables
            private $image;
            private $width;
            private $height;
            private $imageResized;

            function __construct($fileName)
            {
                // *** Open up the file
                $this->image = $this->openImage($fileName);

                // *** Get width and height
                $this->width  = imagesx($this->image);
                $this->height = imagesy($this->image);
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            private function openImage($file)
            {
                // *** Get extension
                $extension = strtolower(strrchr($file, '.'));

                switch($extension)
                {
                    case '.jpg':
                    case '.jpeg':
                        $img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
                        break;
                    case '.gif':
                        $img = @imagecreatefromgif($file);
                        break;
                    case '.png':
                        $img = @imagecreatefrompng($file);
                        break;
                    default:
                        $img = false;
                        break;
                }
                return $img;
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            public function resizeImage($newWidth, $newHeight, $option="auto")
            {
                // *** Get optimal width and height - based on $option
                $optionArray = $this->getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option);

                $optimalWidth  = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
                $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];


                // *** Resample - create image canvas of x, y size
                $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight);
                imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $this->width, $this->height);


                // *** if option is 'crop', then crop too
                if ($option == 'crop') {
                    $this->crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight);
                    return 'ok';
                }
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            private function getDimensions($newWidth, $newHeight, $option)
            {

               switch ($option)
                {
                    case 'exact':
                        $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                        $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                        break;
                    case 'portrait':
                        $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                        $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                        break;
                    case 'landscape':
                        $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                        $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
                        break;
                    case 'auto':
                        $optionArray = $this->getSizeByAuto($newWidth, $newHeight);
                        $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
                        $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
                        break;
                    case 'crop':
                        $optionArray = $this->getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight);
                        $optimalWidth = $optionArray['optimalWidth'];
                        $optimalHeight = $optionArray['optimalHeight'];
                        break;
                }
                return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            private function getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight)
            {
                $ratio = $this->width / $this->height;
                $newWidth = $newHeight * $ratio;
                return $newWidth;
            }

            private function getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth)
            {
                $ratio = $this->height / $this->width;
                $newHeight = $newWidth * $ratio;
                return $newHeight;
            }

            private function getSizeByAuto($newWidth, $newHeight)
            {
                if ($this->height < $this->width)
                // *** Image to be resized is wider (landscape)
                {
                    $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                    $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
                }
                elseif ($this->height > $this->width)
                // *** Image to be resized is taller (portrait)
                {
                    $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                    $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                }
                else
                // *** Image to be resizerd is a square
                {
                    if ($newHeight < $newWidth) {
                        $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                        $optimalHeight= $this->getSizeByFixedWidth($newWidth);
                    } else if ($newHeight > $newWidth) {
                        $optimalWidth = $this->getSizeByFixedHeight($newHeight);
                        $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                    } else {
                        // *** Sqaure being resized to a square
                        $optimalWidth = $newWidth;
                        $optimalHeight= $newHeight;
                    }
                }

                return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            private function getOptimalCrop($newWidth, $newHeight)
            {

                $heightRatio = $this->height / $newHeight;
                $widthRatio  = $this->width /  $newWidth;

                if ($heightRatio < $widthRatio) {
                    $optimalRatio = $heightRatio;
                } else {
                    $optimalRatio = $widthRatio;
                }

                $optimalHeight = $this->height / $optimalRatio;
                $optimalWidth  = $this->width  / $optimalRatio;

                return array('optimalWidth' => $optimalWidth, 'optimalHeight' => $optimalHeight);
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            private function crop($optimalWidth, $optimalHeight, $newWidth, $newHeight)
            {
                // *** Find center - this will be used for the crop
                $cropStartX = ( $optimalWidth / 2) - ( $newWidth /2 );
                $cropStartY = ( $optimalHeight/ 2) - ( $newHeight/2 );

                $crop = $this->imageResized;
                //imagedestroy($this->imageResized);

                // *** Now crop from center to exact requested size
                $this->imageResized = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth , $newHeight);
                imagecopyresampled($this->imageResized, $crop , 0, 0, $cropStartX, $cropStartY, $newWidth, $newHeight , $newWidth, $newHeight);
            }

            ## --------------------------------------------------------

            public function saveImage($savePath, $imageQuality="100")
            {
                // *** Get extension
                $extension = strrchr($savePath, '.');
                   $extension = strtolower($extension);

                switch($extension)
                {
                    case '.jpg':
                    case '.jpeg':
                        if (imagetypes() & IMG_JPG) {
                            imagejpeg($this->imageResized, $savePath, $imageQuality);
                        }
                        break;

                    case '.gif':
                        if (imagetypes() & IMG_GIF) {
                            imagegif($this->imageResized, $savePath);
                        }
                        break;

                    case '.png':
                        // *** Scale quality from 0-100 to 0-9
                        $scaleQuality = round(($imageQuality/100) * 9);

                        // *** Invert quality setting as 0 is best, not 9
                        $invertScaleQuality = 9 - $scaleQuality;

                        if (imagetypes() & IMG_PNG) {
                             imagepng($this->imageResized, $savePath, $invertScaleQuality);
                        }
                        break;

                    // ... etc

                    default:
                        // *** No extension - No save.
                        break;
                }

                imagedestroy($this->imageResized);
            }


            ## --------------------------------------------------------

        }
?>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'orientation'? You don't want to rotate? Don't use the script.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Correct, I do not want to rotate. "Don't use the script", I do want to scale the images.... that is why I use the script....

Comment: I dont see any code that would perform an image rotation. I am also not sure what you mean by rotation. Please add some images as example.

Comment: I just tested your script and I confirm you it does not do any rotation. If you are encountering issue, it means it is coming from somewhere else. The script cant do much about it.

Comment: @alfallouji see edited question. There is something that happens if the images is uploaded from iPhone camera.

Comment: Can you test that : save the original file without using your class and see if you still have the bug. If you still have it, it will confirm that the bug does not relate to your class.

Comment: @alfallouji I tried, and then the image is fine. There seem to be something about the php function getimagesize according to http://www.neilyoungcv.com/blog/code-share/image-resizing-with-php-exif-orientation-fix/. I just tried that script but it stil rotate the image. Exactly as above. Do you understand how to complement this class with that information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Images can have extra information about orientation (= landscape or portrait). See:

http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/exif-orientation.html

This could explain your problem. If you look at:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php

Then you can find this in the comments:

> This function does not honour EXIF orientation data.  Pictures that
>   are rotated using EXIF, will show up in the original orientation after
>   being handled by imagecreatefromjpeg().  Below is a function to create
>   an image from JPEG while honouring EXIF orientation data.

And how you can correct for it:

```
function imagecreatefromjpegexif($filename)
{
    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
    $exif = exif_read_data($filename);
    if ($img && $exif && isset($exif['Orientation']))
    {
        $ort = $exif['Orientation'];

        if ($ort == 6 || $ort == 5)
            $img = imagerotate($img, 270, null);
        if ($ort == 3 || $ort == 4)
            $img = imagerotate($img, 180, null);
        if ($ort == 8 || $ort == 7)
            $img = imagerotate($img, 90, null);

        if ($ort == 5 || $ort == 4 || $ort == 7)
            imageflip($img, IMG_FLIP_HORIZONTAL);
    }
    return $img;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

KIKO Software's answer is very good, but I would like to make a small addition to it. **exif_read_data** is not always available on all machines, so better check if it is available before usage. Also, it produces some unwanted output, so better prepend it with @:

```
  if(function_exists('exif_read_data'))
  {
      $exif = @exif_read_data($filename);
  }
  else
  {
      return $img;
  }
```